# How to add html entites to RSS feeds

Tags: php, unicode, rss, html-entities

I use htmlentities on data that are displaying in RSS and I have unicode characters so they are show entities like `&Aacute;` which service like http://feedvalidator.org/ show as invalid.

How can I add this entities to xml (like using namespace) or should I use different function to escape characters like `& < >`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is function that work in php 5.3.3

```
function encode($string) {
    $result = '';
    foreach (str_split(utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($string))) as $char) {
        $num = ord($char);
        if ($num > 127) {
            $result .= '&#' . $num . ';';
        } else {
            $result .= $char;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to escape characters with special meaning in XML.

Use proper character encoding for other characters.

(Skimming the documentation for `htmlentities` suggests that you could pass `ENT_XML1` and get XML compatible numeric entities if you weren't going to use proper character encoding).

Comment: Thanks, but I have php 5.3.3 and ENT_XML1 was added to 5.4 and htmlspecialchars leave unicode characers and validator show as invalid even if I have document `encoding="utf-8"`

Comment: @jcubic: please post more detail on that error and the code you are using to generate the output. `htmlspecialchars` is quite sufficient for generating XML, you do not need to escape non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I don't remeber because I fix it, but it show something like can't decode character `?a` (the validator).

Comment: The data was taken from MySQL database.